# PrestaShop 1.7 Add new resources and class

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I created new resources with this code:

```
class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore {
public static function getResources(){
    $resources = parent::getResources();

    // if you do not have class for your table
    $resources['test'] = array('description' => 'Manage My API', 'specific_management' => true);

    $resources['categoryecommerce'] = array('description' => 'o jacie marcin', 'class' => 'CategoryEcommerce');

    $mp_resource = Hook::exec('addMobikulResources', array('resources' => $resources), null, true, false);
    if (is_array($mp_resource) && count($mp_resource)) {
        foreach ($mp_resource as $new_resources) {
            if (is_array($new_resources) && count($new_resources)) {
                $resources = array_merge($resources, $new_resources);
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($resources);
    return $resources;
}
}
```

And new class:

```
class CategoryEcommerceCore extends ObjectModelCore {

public $category_id;
public $category_core_id;

public static $definition = array(
    'table' => "category_ecommerce",
    'primary' => 'category_id',
    'fields' => array(
        'category_core_id' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
    )
);

protected $webserviceParameters = array();

}
```

Webservice is override properly. My class WebserviceRequest is copying to 
/override/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest 
but class isn't copying to /override/classes/ when i installing my module.

How to add new resourcess with own logic ? I want to add categories within relation to my table.

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 5):

As soon as there is literally nothing regarding the API except Webkul tutorial... I tried to implement the "Webkul's" tutorial, but also failed. However seems that it's better to use `hooks` instead of overrides. I used my "reverse engineering skills" to determine the way to create that API, so-o-o-o, BEHOLD!  :D

Let's assume you have a custom PrestaShop 1.7 module. Your file is `mymodule.php` and here are several steps.

1. This is an install method wich allows you to register the hook within database (you can uninstall and reinstall the module for this method to be executed):

```
public function install() {

    parent::install();
    $this->registerHook('addWebserviceResources');
    return true;
}
```

2. Add the hook listener:

```
public function hookAddWebserviceResources($resources) {

    $added_resources['test'] = [
        'description' => 'Test',
        'specific_management' => true,
    ];
    return $added_resources;
}
```

That `specific_management` option shows you are going to use WebsiteSpecificManagement file instead of database model file.

3. Create WebsiteSpecificManagement file, called `WebsiteSpecificManagementTest` (Test - is CamelCased name of your endpoint). You can take the skeleton for this file from `/classes/webservice/WebserviceSpecificManagementSearch.php`. Remove everything except:

   - setObjectOutput
   - setWsObject
   - getWsObject
   - getObjectOutput
   - setUrlSegment
   - getUrlSegment
   - getContent (should return `$this->output;` and nothing more)
   - manage - you should rewrite it to return/process the data you want.
4. Add

```
include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'YOURMODULENAME/classes/WebserviceSpecificManagementTest.php');
```

to your module file (haven't figured out how to include automatically).

5. Go to `/Backoffice/index.php?controller=AdminWebservice` and setup the new "Auth" key for your application, selecting the `test` endpoint from the permissions list. Remember the key.
6. Visit `/api/test?ws_key=YOUR_KEY_GENERATED_ON_STEP_4` and see the XML response.
7. Add `&output_format=JSON` to your URL to see the response in JSON.
   You have to use something like `$this->output = json_encode(['blah' => 'world'])` within `manage` method at `WebsiteSpecificManagementTest`.

Comment: My tip is that if You want to add another endpoint, like: `custom_task`, or have already install module but it hasn't hook on it's first install, then it's better to uninstall module, and then install it again, to see (add), `custom_task` endpoint to Webservice endpoints list.